# CO2 dataset from Scripps is broken. How can in inform the owner?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, environment, csv

I'm using the daily CO2 measurement dataset from the Scripps CO2 Program

Data page: https://scrippsco2.ucsd.edu/data/atmospheric_co2/mlo.html

Direct link to daily dataset: https://scrippsco2.ucsd.edu/assets/data/atmospheric/stations/in_situ_co2/daily/daily_in_situ_co2_mlo.csv

---

You'll see in the "good" csv, that the data continues to almost the present day.

[image: good data csv]

Archived "good" csv: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/co2birthdate/dataops/4d2ed6fd5b3987be8b6ce502d592949414275920/input_data/daily_in_situ_co2_mlo.csv

While in the "broken" csv, it's spotty data and only until 2006.

[image: bad data csv]

Archived "broken" csv: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/co2birthdate/dataops/9edf3968806266774e5f97865f9f368d368e8c9c/input_data/daily_in_situ_co2_mlo.csv

--

I suspect that something is broken in the data owner's pipeline, but I haven't been able to bring it to their attention.

I've tried:

- Emailing the person listed in the "data sharing policy"

[image]

- Contacting them on Twitter: https://twitter.com/philshem/status/1323338982084780033?s=20
- Emailing webmaster@ucsd.edu and webmaster@scrippsco2.ucsd.edu

---

### How can I report this "broken" dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via some emails, I was able to make contact with some people responsible for the data - and they have informed me that the daily CSV has been corrected.

https://scrippsco2.ucsd.edu/assets/data/atmospheric/stations/in_situ_co2/daily/daily_in_situ_co2_mlo.csv